# iteration and add two values in each iteration r

Tags: r

I have a data frame (df) with around 100,000 entries (df$col). I want to iterate over each value and add previous all values to compare them with the rest in each iteration (loop) in r; something like following:

First iteration:

[1] vs [2 ....n]

second iteration:

[1+2] vs [3 ....n]

up to

[1....n-1] vs [n]

I have tried to write a simple following code in r:

```
aa <- function(df) {
     df <- data.table(d, key = "a")
     m <-df[, sum(x), by="b"]
     nm <-df[, sum(y), by="c"]
     for (i in m$V1)
       l <- i+1
       m <- nm$V1 - l
       print(l, m)
}
```

Any ideas, how can I implement it in a better way? Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful to know what the structure of your data is.  In your code, you reference columns `a,b,c,x,y`, but don't mention that anywhere.

Comment: Hi, its a df&col with "numeric" values.

Comment: That doesn't clarify it for me. Could you please add the output from `head(df)` to your question?  It would be even more helpful if you also gave a simple reproducible example showing input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your ultimate purpose. If you want to partition your vector (or data.frame column) into two pieces of same weight (sum of elements), you may try splitting the vector elements in half: `[50% | 50%]`, then repeatedly splitting the heavier partition in half (again in terms of number of elements, thus getting either `[75% | 25%]` or `[25% | 75%]`), and so on. There may be an exact solution or not (for example, for the vector `1,1,1,5`), and there may be any number of solutions, meaning you will have to adapt this basic O(log n) binary search.

If you really want to display all of the pairs of weights, you might try the following in O(n):

```
aa=function(df,colname) #arguments: data frame and name (or index) of column
{
    #let's trust the input is sane and go ahead:
    x=df[,colname]
    total=sum(x)
    elems=length(x) #could use nrow(df)
    upper=0
    for(i in 1:(elems-1))
    {
        upper=upper+x[i]
        cat(sep="","First ",i," vs. the other ",elems - i,": ",upper," vs. ",total - upper,"\n") #could use sprintf() for nicer formatting
    }
    #return anything if wanted
}
```

Comment: I need to run a function (let's say t-test(x,y); x=first value, y=second) on both values in each iteration.

Comment: Right, then you can use function `FUN(upper, total - upper)` at the end of the for-loop. (Even though the function could not be `t.test()`, as there would be no variances to base the test on.)